# Import function issue from file issue python

Tags: python

Not able to import the function from file.Don't know the issue.Please help.

**main.py**

```
import csv
from matches_played_per_year import compute_and_plot_matches_played_per_year
```

The file structure is

[image: File structure]

Comment: You should have from instead of import on the second line

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: @Azy_Crw4282 sorry please look at the question again.Changed

Comment: Can you show the error message please

Comment: Insufficient information to locate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just need `.` before file.py in same folder

`from .matches_played_per_year import compute_and_plot_matches_played_per_year`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to update your `PYTHONPATH`

`export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/matches_played_per_year`

where `/path/to` is the absolute path to this file/module.

If that doesn't work, just to be sure what you can do is:

`import matches_played_per_year`

And then to use this you would do:

`matches_played_per_year.compute_and_plot_matches_played_per_year()`

A good tip: `sudo apt-get install tree && cd ~ && tree ipl` <- ipl since it seems like that is the name of your root folder.

Then copy-paste that into code blocks so that we don't have to click suspicious links and can copy-paste from your text.

[not recommended] If you want to be thorough, add every possible path of your project to your `PYTHONPATH`

Looking at the image you added that would be:

`export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/ipl:/path/to/ipl/tests:/path/to/ipl/Match_Delivery_Analyze`